# USB host/peripheral design

Tags: usb, microcontroller, hardware-interface

I'm looking to create a device that acts as a host to a USB peripheral, format the data, then send it out to another host (the PC). Are on-the-go chips capable of accomplishing this or would you need to implement both a host USB microcontroller and a peripheral USB controller? I don't see much information out there for creating a middleman that performs data molding for USB prior to reaching a host. Any information would be appreciated, hopefully I didn't butcher this concept.

Comment: USB OTG may be a host or device but not at the same time. USB OTG socket contains ID pin that allows you to determine whether your USB is a host or a device at the moment. So you need to start a proper software stack (HAL, driver, supported classes and protocols). But the sortware is different for host and device.

Comment: As Anthony G. pointed out, picking a part also requires an estimate of the data rate required - if you only need to man-in-the-middle something like a mouse it will be a lot easier than a webcam or a disk drive.

Comment: In the end I used two controllers with SPI data bus in between. One controller acted as a host and the other as a device. This turned out to work well. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a microcontroller with 2 USB busses.
One should act as a host, and the other as a slave.
You will need to implement them both.
USB OTG is used to create a host and a slave in 1 device with 1 connector,
so it's impossible to use them together at the same time.